# SignalR connection related basic query

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i am new in signalr and trying to learn it.one guy said **gives you two programming models over that connection (hubs and persistent connections).**

can anyone tell me what is **signalr hub and persistent connections**
what is deference between them ?

why one should use persistent connections and when one should use hub

when i was working with signalr then i create a class which extend hub not persistent connections. so i just like to have good know what is persistent connections and when i extend it ? if possible discuss with patient. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ramp up, read our documentation.
[SignalR Wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki)
[SignalR Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server)